# Python Primes Array Confusion

Tags: python, math, primes

I have a small question about this python prime checking function. This is really dumb, but what does the `[2]` in the in the `for n in [2]` do?

I understand the formula to check for primes, no problem, but can't figure out what that `[2]` is for.

from: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_and_Math

```
from math import ceil
def prime(input):
    for n in [2] + range(3, int(ceil(input**0.5)), 2):
        if input%n == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Thanks for answering my dumb question.

Comment: Its a simply concatenation of lists, where [2] is a list

Comment: I think is because the `for in` instruction requires a list to iterate. There is a sum of two lists [2] and the one that yields the `range` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply list addition:

```
>>> range(3, 10, 2)
[3, 5, 7, 9]
>>> [2] + range(3, 10, 2)
[2, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

i.e. they want to check divisibility by 2, but there is obviously no need to check divisibility by 4, 6, 8... so with this operation it is "prepending" a 2 onto the beginning of a list of odd numbers.

By the way, this function is broken - it returns `prime(2) == False` and `prime(1) == True` which are both wrong.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. I did notice that about the false results for 2 and 1 and more interested in the list addition issue.

Comment: And why on hell is 9 checked?

Comment: For the same reason 25, 49, 121 are (i.e. primes squared).  This algorithm uses `range(3, int(ceil(input**0.5)), 2)` which is incorrect, you should check in `range(3, int(1 + input**0.5), 2)` instead.